# Error in data receiver after changing DB login to LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After following this tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/Connect%2Bthe%2BWSO2%2BAPI%2BManager%2Bto%2Ban%2BExternal%2BLDAP%2BUser%2BStore
to enable the LDAP authentication in WSO2 API Manager I restart the server and appear this error:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-30 14:26:39,274] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to login to data receiver :/xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: wrong userName or password
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:42)
        ... 7 more
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-30 14:26:39,274] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:93)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: wrong userName or password
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:42)
        ... 7 more
```

But the server start correctly and I can login with the LDAP users. So, how can I control that message or edit the user/password that is referencing in the error because I think that is checking the default wso2 authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can happen when using binary data publisher for throttling and the username or password is incorrect. Related configuration is located inside "ThrottlingConfigurations" section of "repository/conf/api-manager.xml" file. Try to update the Username and Password inside the "DataPublisher" configuration to the LDAP user.

```
<ThrottlingConfigurations>
    <EnableAdvanceThrottling>true</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
    <DataPublisher>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Type>Binary</Type>
        <ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:${receiver.url.port}</ReceiverUrlGroup>
        <AuthUrlGroup>ssl://${carbon.local.ip}:${auth.url.port}</AuthUrlGroup>
        <Username>user_name</Username>
        <Password>password</Password>

  ....
</ThrottlingConfigurations>
```

Comment: I checked that configuration and in the <username> and <password> tags it have the variables ${admin.username} and ${admin.password} so I just take a look again to the configuration and in the manual that i followed it says that the password must be empty so I did not make that, I put the LDAP admin password and it worked, thanks for give me the idea Mr. Ranga